# Google maps is returning restaurants, shops etc in autosuggest

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to make a geocoder which only works with roads, cities, towns and countries. However, if I type in something like "Papa Johns Pizza" it is returning me results.

How can I make it so google is working on addresses and remove places of business?

This is the code im working from:
http://jsfiddle.net/qcPgL/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/aleation/pqmQ5/1/

adding

```
var autocompleteOptions = {
       types: ['geocode']
};
```

and assigning those options to the autocomplete

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, autocompleteOptions);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry but im having a hard time. This is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/BxG9H/  Ive added the first bit no problem, but I cant find where to add the second bit

Comment: In the new jsfiddle you pasted, it's correct, you can even (and should) remove the autocompleteOptions var.

In the first fiddle it's using google places library, that's why it shows up businesses, the one you pasted on the comment is using Google Maps Api geocder, and Jquery autocomplete, instead of googlemaps autocomplete: 
Only Google maps autocomplete shows up businesses if you want.

What happens is that you got a exception there, and someone put Papa john's pizza as a location instead of a business, try searching for "new York" in the first fiddle you posted and the second one :)